# how to open a jasper report exporting to pdf in a new window

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I have been exporting jasper report to pdf but it opens in the same window which is a problem to me because if i want to go to previous page i cant be able to go to previous page so i thought of opening pdf page in a new window but i dont have any idea of how to open it in a new window.

sample1.jsp

```
<%@ page  import="java.io.*"%> 
<%@ page  import="java.sql.Connection"%> 
<%@ page  import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@ page  import="java.util.HashMap"%>
<%@ page  import="java.util.Map"%>
<%@ page  import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"%>
<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>
<%@ page import="java.text.ParseException" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.File" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.FileInputStream" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.FileNotFoundException" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.InputStream" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.SQLException" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.FileOutputStream" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.OutputStream" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.HashMap" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Map" %>
<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.*" %> 
<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.*" %>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignQuery"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRResultSetDataSource"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRCsvDataSource"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.ooxml.JRDocxExporter"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
Connection conn = null;
String cate=(String)session.getAttribute("cat");
String stat=(String)session.getAttribute("sta");
String dayy=(String)session.getAttribute("da");
String monthh=(String)session.getAttribute("mon");
String yearr=(String)session.getAttribute("yea");
String dayy1=(String)session.getAttribute("da1");
String monthh1=(String)session.getAttribute("mon1");
String yearr1=(String)session.getAttribute("yea1");
System.out.println("2 is:"+cate);
System.out.println("4 is:"+stat);
System.out.println("5 is:"+dayy);
System.out.println("6 is:"+monthh);
System.out.println("7 is:"+yearr);
System.out.println("8 is:"+dayy1);
System.out.println("9 is:"+monthh1);
System.out.println("10 is:"+yearr1);
try 
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/marketing_database","root","root");
    String sql="select * from lead where Status='" + stat.replaceAll("\\'","''") + "'";
           sql+=" AND Category='" + cate.replaceAll("\\'","''") + "'";
           sql+=" AND DATE(Lead_Date)>='" + yearr + "-" + monthh + "-" + dayy + "'"; 
           sql+=" AND DATE(Lead_Date)<='" + yearr1 + "-" + monthh1 + "-" + dayy1 + "'";
    String jrxmlFile ="D:/dev/tools/jasper files/report3.jrxml";
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(jrxmlFile));
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(input);

    System.out.println("Compiling Report Designs");
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

    System.out.println("Creating JasperPrint Object");
    HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    map.put("sql",sql);
            byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(jasperReport, map, conn);

            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
            ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
            outStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
}
catch(Exception e) 
{e.printStackTrace();} 

        %>
</body>
</html>
```

view.jsp

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function setAction(nPage){

        document.forms[0].action = nPage;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<%
String category=request.getParameter("category");
session.setAttribute("cat",category);
String status=request.getParameter("status");
session.setAttribute("sta",status);
System.out.println("status is:"+status);
String day=request.getParameter("day");
session.setAttribute("da",day);
String month=request.getParameter("month");
session.setAttribute("mon",month);
String year=request.getParameter("year");
session.setAttribute("yea",year);
String day1=request.getParameter("day1");
session.setAttribute("da1",day1);
String month1=request.getParameter("month1");
session.setAttribute("mon1",month1);
String year1=request.getParameter("year1");
session.setAttribute("yea1",year1);
%>
<select onchange="setAction(this.value)">
<option value=''> Make a selection </option>
<option value='sample1.jsp'> PDF</option>
<option value='XLS_LEAD.jsp'> XLS </option>
<option value='DOC_LEAD.jsp'> DOC </option>
<option value='XLSX_LEAD.jsp'> XLSX </option>
</select>
<br/>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Use javascript when you like to open the pdf window.open("the path to my pdf generating page")

Comment: @PetterFriberg where i have to write "window.open("the path to my pdf generating page")"

Comment: You have two options when you do your search. 1)Show another page in browser and then open your pdf (you can use tag body onLoad) 2) Instead of having your search redirect to new page make it open a new window the pdf result. (you remain on search page). If you include your search page code in this question and tell me what you like I will help you with the answer

Comment: @PetterFriberg    i have included two jsp's here,one is "view.jsp" and another is "sample1.jsp". when i select an option(sample1.jsp) in "view.jsp" and click on "submit",it should open in a new window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your view.jsp

I can see that you already have put all variables into the session you are only using the form to select to which page you need to go.

You can do something like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function generateReport() {
  var e = document.getElementById("idOfYourSelectYouNeedToAddedIt");
  var strPage = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  window.open(strPage);
  return false; //This make you stay on this page;
  //return true; //Set the action tag in the form to the page you like to go to!
 }
</script>


 <form name="myForm"  onsubmit="return generateReport()">
      <select id = "idOfYourSelectYouNeedToAddedIt">
      <option value=''> Make a selection </option>
      ..... the other option values
 </form>
```

Note if you like to go to another page you can simple add action tag to your `form` tag and return true in the `generateReport()` function

example

```
 <form name="myForm" action="thisIsWhereILikeToGo.jsp"  onsubmit="return generateReport()">
```

Note: You should remove the `onchange="setAction(this.value)` code, it has no use anymore and consider checking that `strPage` is not empty, no selection...

Comment: Once again Thanks a lot